# Button doesn't appear in android appwidget layout

Tags: android, layout, refresh, android-appwidget

I have this xml file as a layout of an appwidget:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <!-- ListView to be shown on widget -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewWidget"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refresh_appwidget"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="refresh"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

The button is not displayed, and I don't know the cause. I tested layout_with match_parent but always the same result.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Your button is not displayed because of the size of your listview. Your button is under the listview.

Comment: Don't declare "wrap_content" for `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a fixed height for the listview for example `android:layout_height="400dp"` in LinearLayout.

Or use a `RelativeLayout`

Or add your button as a footer to listview. So you can see the button when you scroll down

Or add your button as a header to listview.

With Relative layout you can place the button at the top or button and relative tot eh button you can place your listview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with **RelativeLayout**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

<!--     ListView to be shown on widget -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewWidget"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/refresh_appwidget"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="refresh"

 />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I try and see the Button but dont see the List

Comment: with this both are displayed but the list is below the button

Comment: @begiPass try the layout in my post it should work or set eh height to `android:layout_height="400dp"` for listview. change it to desired value

Comment: @Raghunandan, yes thank you, it works fine and looks pretty good